# Input-store-store-output

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I can't get the function to do some storing of values on another page and outputting it on the next page.
For example, I have dog.html and cat.html that has a submit button respectively. I want to get the inputs of dog.html and cat.html and output the values on pay.html(after clicking the submit button in cat.html

I have this code in pay4.html where I can get the value from the previous page.

```
function getParams(){
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    var params = new Array();
    if (idx != -1) {
        var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1,
                document.URL.length).split('&');
        for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
            nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
            params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
        }
    }
    return params;
}
params = getParams();
Name = unescape(params["Name"]);
Address = unescape(params["Address"]);
ContactNo = unescape(params["ContactNo"]);
Email = unescape(params["Email"]);
document.write("Name: " + Name + "<br>");
document.write("Address: " + Address + "<br>");
document.write("Contact number: " + ContactNo + "<br>");
document.write("E-mail: " + Email + "<br>");
```

I need to do this to input again in some pages before outputting all the values I entered.

```
<form name="info" action="pay1.html" type=GET>
<form name="info" action="pay2.html" type=GET>
<form name="info" action="pay3.html" type=GET>
<form name="info" action="pay4.html" type=GET>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using cookies to carry your data across several pages (assuming they're on same domain). 
If it was running on a server, you can use sessions.

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie